# python matplotlib : ploting 3d surface from string indexed arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my problem : I have a hierarchy of subfolders that each contain a file with a value. For example :

- folder1/

  - folderA/result.xml
  - folderB/result.xml
  - folderC/result.xml
- folder2/

  - folderA/result.xml
  - folderB/result.xml
  - folderC/result.xml
- folder3/

  - folderA/result.xml
  - folderB/result.xml
  - folderC/result.xml

I would like to draw a surface with matplotlib with folder1 to folder3 as X values, folderA to folderC as Y value and the corresponding result (from each result.xml file) as Z value. But I don't know how to generate the Z array so that matplotlib can properly plot the surface.

For the sake of clarity, let's say that I have two arrays :

```
x = ["folder1", "folder2", "folder3"]
y = ["folderA", "folderB", "folderC"]
X,Y = numpy.meshgrid (x,y)
```

How do I generate the Z array so I can use it as follow :

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
```

My question concern only the actual creation of the array (dimension and filling), not the accessing the XML file or going through the subfolders.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might first convert your x, y coordinates to integers:

```
import numpy as np
xi = np.arange(len(x))
yi = np.arange(len(y))
Xi, Yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
```

For Z array you will need a value for *each* pair of x and y (that is `('folder1', 'folderA'), ('folder1', 'folderB')...`). You can do that in a for loop:

```
Z = np.zeros(Xi.shape)
for i in xi:
    for j in xj:
        xy_pair = (xi[i], yi[j])
        Z[j,i] = calcZ(xy_pair)
```

I guess that the logic behind the `calcZ` function depends on how you parse data from the XML files.

For clarity, in the plot you can change the tick labels to represent the folders/files that you accessed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

# ... plot some stuff ...

ax.set_xticks(xi)
ax.set_yticks(yi)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
ax.set_yticklabels(y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Except for a few minor errors, it worked fine ! Thank you for your help.

`np.range()` doesn't exist, I used `np.arange()` instead.

`Z[i,j]` the indices were in the wrong order, `Z[j,i]` workded.